# WSO2 ESB: Can we count number of hits from the same IP with in the time limit

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

In WSO2 ESB how can we find the number of hits from the same IP address or the same user is trying to keep our system busy. How can we secure our application in that system.

Is there any feature available in the WSO2 ESB to count the number of hits per IP address or user with in the time limit?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are talking about Throttling. WSO2 ESB supports [Throttling](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Throttling), a mechanism to control access to the services at different levels. You can use IP based throttling for your usecase.